# Call a method from another application in a vb.net application

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking to execute a method of another running application from a vb.net application (method running in the called application).
Let's say we have the following in the application to be called (A.exe):

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    'Imagine this does something in this app
End Sub
```

(or a different situation, the application to be called is written in C#)

```
public void DoSomething(){
    // Imagine this does something in this app
}
```

and I would like to have a way to do the following (Imagine it works as simple as this) (B.exe)

```
Sub Main()
    p = Process.Start("A.exe")
    RunMethod("A.exe", DoSomething())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can call a specific method from "source application" to "destination application"

But there is a different way you can handle it.

If the destination application is a dotnet application (even other applications), you can override "Application.starup" event. It can receive arguments.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx

When you trigger the process send an argument as hint to the other process application event, then you can call, what ever you want from destination application.

Comment: well since I just got downvoted i'll assume this was a pretty stupid question so i'll take this and mark your answer as the correct one since this helps too.

Comment: I dont know who down voted. It is a good question actually. I will make it up.

Comment: thanks, are you ok if i unmark the answer to see if someone else can clarify me if i can call a specific method from source app to destination app?

Comment: It's been a few years. I have neglected to login to SO for a long time after being discouraged by my first question not being up to standards. I have however used the method you mention in other applications and as such it counts as a valid answer. Thank you for wanting to help so long ago.